# Are function-local static mutexes thread-safe?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following program I attempt the make the `print` function thread-safe by using a function-local mutex object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>


void print(const std::string & s)
{    
    // Thread safe?
    static std::mutex mtx;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    std::cout <<s << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::thread([&](){ for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) print("a" + std::to_string(i)); }).detach();
    std::thread([&](){ for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) print("b" + std::to_string(i)); }).detach();
    std::thread([&](){ for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) print("c" + std::to_string(i)); }).detach();
    std::thread([&](){ for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) print("d" + std::to_string(i)); }).detach();
    std::thread([&](){ for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) print("e" + std::to_string(i)); }).detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}
```

Is this safe?

My doubts arise from  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955921/thread-safe-initialization-of-function-local-static-const-objects), which presents a similar case.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## C++11

In C++11 and later versions: **yes, this pattern is safe**. In particular, initialization of [function-local static variables is thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1661529/149138), so your code above works safely across threads.

The way this works in practice is that the compiler inserts any necessary boilerplate in the function itself to check if the variable is initialized prior to access. In the case of `std::mutex` as implemented in `gcc`, `clang` and `icc`, however, the initialized state is *all-zeros*, so no explicit initialization is needed (the variable will live in the all-zeros `.bss` section so the initialization is "free"), as we see from [the assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/9vcSXR)<sup>1</sup>:

```
inc(int& i):
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:_ZL28__gthrw___pthread_key_createPjPFvPvE
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L2
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdi
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZZ3incRiE3mtx
        call    _ZL26__gthrw_pthread_mutex_lockP15pthread_mutex_t
        test    eax, eax
        jne     .L10
        add     DWORD PTR [rbx], 1
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZZ3incRiE3mtx
        pop     rbx
        jmp     _ZL28__gthrw_pthread_mutex_unlockP15pthread_mutex_t
.L2:
        add     DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
        ret
.L10:
        mov     edi, eax
        call    _ZSt20__throw_system_errori
```

Note that starting at the line `mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZZ3incRiE3mtx` it simply loads the address of the `inc::mtx` function-local static and calls `pthread_mutex_lock` on it, without any initialization. The code before that dealing with `pthread_key_create` is apparently just checking if the pthreads library [is present at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46369679/149138).

There's no guarantee, however, that all implementations will implement `std::mutex` as all-zeros, so you might in some cases incur ongoing overhead on each call to check if the `mutex` has been initialized. Declaring the mutex outside the function would avoid that.

Here's [an example](https://godbolt.org/g/eVhPdV) contrasting the two approaches with a stand-in `mutex2` class with a non-inlinable constructor (so the compiler can't determine that the initial state is all-zeros):

```
#include <mutex>

class mutex2 {
    public:
    mutex2();
    void lock(); 
    void unlock();
 };

void inc_local(int &i)
{    
    // Thread safe?
    static mutex2 mtx;
    std::unique_lock<mutex2> lock(mtx);
    i++;
}

mutex2 g_mtx;

void inc_global(int &i)
{    
    std::unique_lock<mutex2> lock(g_mtx);
    i++;
}
```

The function-local version compiles (on `gcc`) to:

```
inc_local(int& i):
        push    rbx
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR _ZGVZ9inc_localRiE3mtx[rip]
        mov     rbx, rdi
        test    al, al
        jne     .L3
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZGVZ9inc_localRiE3mtx
        call    __cxa_guard_acquire
        test    eax, eax
        jne     .L12
.L3:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZZ9inc_localRiE3mtx
        call    _ZN6mutex24lockEv
        add     DWORD PTR [rbx], 1
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZZ9inc_localRiE3mtx
        pop     rbx
        jmp     _ZN6mutex26unlockEv
.L12:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZZ9inc_localRiE3mtx
        call    _ZN6mutex2C1Ev
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZGVZ9inc_localRiE3mtx
        call    __cxa_guard_release
        jmp     .L3
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZGVZ9inc_localRiE3mtx
        call    __cxa_guard_abort
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    _Unwind_Resume
```

Note the large amount of boilerplate dealing with the `__cxa_guard_*` functions. First, a rip-relative flag byte, `_ZGVZ9inc_localRiE3mtx`<sup>2</sup> is checked and if non-zero, the variable has already been initialized and we are done and fall into the fast-path. No atomic operations are needed because on x86, loads already have the needed *acquire* semantics.

If this check fails, we go to the slow path, which is essentially a form of [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking): the initial check is not sufficient to determine that the variable needs initialization because two or more threads may be racing here. The `__cxa_guard_acquire` call does the locking and the second check, and may either fall through to the fast path as well (if another thread concurrently initialized the object), or may jump dwon to the actual initialization code at `.L12`.

Finally note that the last 5 instructions in the assembly aren't direct reachable from the function at all as they are preceded by an unconditional `jmp     .L3` and nothing jumps to them. They are there to be jumped to by an exception handler should the call to the constructor `mutex2()` throw an exception at some point.

Overall, we can say that the runtime cost of the first-access initialization is low to moderate because the fast-path only checks a single byte flag without any expensive instructions (and the remainder of the function itself usually implies at least two atomic operations for `mutex.lock()` and `mutex.unlock()`, but it comes at a significant code size increase.

Compare to the global version, which is identical except that initialization happens during global initialization rather than before first access:

```
inc_global(int& i):
    push    rbx
    mov     rbx, rdi
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:g_mtx
    call    _ZN6mutex24lockEv
    add     DWORD PTR [rbx], 1
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:g_mtx
    pop     rbx
    jmp     _ZN6mutex26unlockEv
```

The function is less than a third of the size without any initialization boilerplate at all.

### Prior to C++11

Prior to C++11, however, this is generally not safe, unless your compiler makes some special guarantees about the way in which static locals are initialized.

Some time ago, while looking at a similar issue, I examined the assembly generated by Visual Studio for this case.  The pseudocode for the generated assembly code for your `print` method looked something like this:

```
void print(const std::string & s)
{    
    if (!init_check_print_mtx) {
        init_check_print_mtx = true;
        mtx.mutex();  // call mutex() ctor for mtx
    }
    
    // ... rest of method
}
```

The `init_check_print_mtx` is a compiler generated global variable specific to this method which tracks whether the local static has been initialized.  Note that inside the "one time" initialize block guarded by this variable, that the variable is set to true before the mutex is initialized.

I though this was silly since it ensures that other threads racing into this method will skip the initializer and use a uninitialized `mtx` - versus the alternative of possibly initializing `mtx` more than once - but in fact doing it this way allows you to avoid the infinite recursion issue that occurs if `std::mutex()` were to call back into print, and this behavior is in fact mandated by the standard.

Nemo above mentions that this has been fixed (more precisely, re-specified) in C++11 to require a wait for all racing threads, which would make this safe, but you'll need to check your own compiler for compliance. I didn't check if in fact the new spec includes this guarantee, but I wouldn't be at all surprised given that local statics were pretty much useless in multi-threaded environments without this (except perhaps for primitive values which didn't have any check-and-set behavior because they just referred directly to an already initialized location in the .data segment).

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that I changed the `print()` function to a slightly simpler `inc()` function that just increments an integer in the locked region. This has the same locking structure and implications as the original, but avoids a bunch of code dealing with the `<<` operators and `std::cout`.

<sup>2</sup> Using `c++filt` this de-mangles to `guard variable for inc_local(int&)::mtx`.

Comment: [Here is a Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6626706/768469) citing chapter and verse of the C++11 standard.  Well, a draft of the standard, anyway.

Comment: Just need to beware if the function is called recursively, in which case `std::recursive_mutex` needs to be used instead. Burned myself with a deadlock before I realized the function holding the lock was calling another function that called the original function... yikes.

Answer (score 17):

This is not the same as the linked question for several reasons.

The linked question is not C++11, but yours is. In C++11 initialization of function-local static variables is always safe. Prior to C++11 it was only safe with some compilers e.g. GCC and Clang default to thread-safe initialization.

The linked question initializes the reference by calling a function, which is *dynamic initialization* and happens at run-time. The default constructor for `std::mutex` is `constexpr` so your static variable has *constant initialization*, i.e. the mutex can be initialized at compile-time (or link-time) so there is nothing to do dynamically at runtime. Even if multiple threads call the function concurrently there's nothing they actually need to do before using the mutex.

Your code is safe (assuming your compiler implements the C++11 rules correctly.)

Comment: Interesting, going to check one's assumptions on the stuff, and seing an 1,5 year-old post edited :)

Comment: Are you sure about the statement that "In C++11 initialization of static variables is always safe."? Do you just mean function-local statics, or is correct initialization order for global statics now guaranteed? (I'm pretty sure that the latter is not true, because I've seen a segfault be fixed by turning a global static `boost::bimap` into a function-local static.)

Comment: Function-local statics only.

Comment: Does *constant initialization* also mean that the compiler won't need to store some kind of flag to indicate whether or not the function-local static has already been initialized or not each time it is accessed?

Comment: @KyleStrand: Function-local statics are thread-safe in C++11 but they remain unsafe when there is circular dependency in initializers due to mutual recursion/re-entrancy.  Globals are of course also unsafe if circularly dependent.

Answer (score 6):

As long as the mutex is static, yes.

Local, nonstatic would defintely NOT be safe. Unless all your threads use the same stack, which also means you've now invented memory where one cell can hold many different values at the same time, and are just waiting for the Nobel committee to notify you for the next Nobel prize.

You must have some sort of "global" (shared) memory space for mutexes.

Comment: But the variable used is `static` - isn't that shared?

Comment: Doh, I missed the "static" altogether - was that edited in afterwards? ;) I've edited. Hopefully no one else noticed... :)

Comment: As an aside, this works because C+11 codified the "Meyers singleton" pattern.  If multiple threads hit the static local for the first time at once, all but one will block until the object (in this case, a `std::mutex`) is initialized.

Comment: @user166390 as long as the mutex has recursive flag, it doesn't matter.