# Is returning local static object thread safe for pre-c++11 compilers

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, singleton

Is this singleton thread safe for the pre-C++11 compilers ?
As we know for C++11 it is thread safe.

```
class Singleton
{
private:
   Singleton(){};

public:
   static Singleton& instance()
   {
      static Singleton INSTANCE;
      return INSTANCE;
   }
};
```

Comment: Forget threadsafe, is that code even *valid*?

Comment: @MorphingDragon can't see why it wouldn't be valid...

Comment: @MorphingDragon why not ??

Comment: @MorphingDragon: You only need to add a default constructor implementation and it compile

Comment: @MorphingDragon : thanks and Edited... now waiting for ans :)

Comment: Prior to C++11 the standard didn't even *know what a thread was*, so its kinda difficult for that to be threadsafe. Your implementation might offer such a guarantee though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++11 what makes this thread safe is the following from the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `6.7` *Declaration statement* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> The zero-initialization (8.5) of all block-scope variables with static
>   storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) is
>   performed before any other initialization takes place. [...] Otherwise
>   such a variable is initialized the first time control passes through
>   its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the
>   completion of its initialization. If the initialization exits by
>   throwing an exception, the initialization is not complete, so it will
>   be tried again the next time control enters the declaration. **If
>   control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is
>   being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion
>   of the initialization.** [...]

while pre C++11 section `6.7` says:

> [...]Otherwise such an object is initialized the first time control passes
>   through its declaration; such an object is considered initialized upon
>   the completion of its initialization. If the initialization exits by
>   throwing an exception, the initialization is not complete, so it will
>   be tried again the next time control enters the declaration.[...]

which does not have the same guarantee that C++11 has and so it would seem pre C++11 it is not specified and therefore you can not count on it. Although this does not prevent implementations from making stronger guarantees.

This make sense since pre C++11 the memory model did not including threading.

Comment: Note, this did not prevent compiler pre-C++11 from [providing a stronger guarantee](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14111952/1708801)