# How to initialize a thread safe static constant vector inside a function in C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
bool function()
{

static const vector<unsigned char>header = {0x00 , 0x01 , 0x02};

//use header

}
```

Threads could be active before initialization in a constructor in the class using my function

Comment: This is [thread safe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27286444/1708801) while C++03 this was not.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: feel free to close it as dup. I would do it if I had close votes left.

Comment: @lpapp I answered the question I linked so I won't dup hammer close it see [this meta thread](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277126/1708801) .. not clear to me if it is an exact dup although clearly related.

Comment: @lpapp: what's your relation to the OP?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: have no clue why it would be abuse. Although it is possible that the other question is dup, too.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I am the OP's 6th sense.

Comment: @lpapp well I think George's point is that since it is a unilateral action you need to be extra sensitive to how others may perceive a conflict of interest. I am never quite sure what should be considered dups so unless it is blindingly obvious I usually tend not to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I think it is blindingly obvious, but we can always reopen it if you make a mistake. We do not hold grudges, at least I do not. ;-) Thank you for your link.

Answer (score 4):

It's already tread safe.

Now isn't that nice.