# Does c++11 make sure static local variable be initialized only once in a thread-safe manner?

Tags: c++

When `class B` is used as a static local variable in `class A` constructor, does c++11 will make sure `func()` be initialized only once in a thread-safe manner? Are the codes commented out redundant?

```
void func() {}

class B {
  B() {
    //static std::atomic<char> first_call(1);
    //if (first_call.fetch_and((char)0)) {
      func();
    //} 
  }
};

class A {
  A(){
    static B;
  }
};
```

Comment: if you want to be more explicit, there is also [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once)

Comment: Also see [Is returning local static object thread safe for pre-c++11 compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27286444/1708801)

Comment: [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) explains it in detail.