# How efficient is thread-safe initialisation of local static variables?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, static-variables

In VC 2015, and recent versions of Clang and GCC (and according to the C++11 standard), initialisation of local static variables is thread-safe.

How efficient is the actual implementation of this in the above compilers? Do they use a mutex?

I'm thinking of writing a high performance logging library that uses a static object at each call site (like [Ayxia Trace](https://github.com/jmatzen/trace-client/blob/master/include/trace/trace.h#L270)) - will that be slow?

Comment: Initialisation of a static variable happens _once_ for each run of the program, so issues of "efficiency" are not likely to be important.

Comment: It's actually compiler implementation specific. GCC and Clang are open source, you could check yourself what's used for that.

Comment: @NeilButterworth but checking if the initialisation has been done yet happens every time the function is called. It's not slow though, and if you need the functionality you won't be able to do something faster by hand.

Comment: @Jonatan Fair point.

Comment: _@Timmmm_ I don't really know what's actually used, but I believe it shouldn't be a mutex. Rather some `std::atomic<bool>` like thingy.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013650/threadsafe-lazy-initialization-static-vs-stdcall-once-vs-double-checked-locki

Comment: @Jon That check has to be done anyway, but it doesn't have to be thread safe, as it's a good candidate for double-checked locking.

Comment: @Timmmm, recent versions of GCC like 4.0, released 12 years ago.

Comment: @Neil _"but it doesn't have to be thread safe"_ According to the current standard it has to be thread safe. That's guaranteed.

Comment: @πάντα  The initial check for initialisation doesn't need to be thread-safe - the initialisation itself does.

Comment: For GCC andClang http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#once-ctor describes the API (but not the implementation details)

Comment: @NeilButterworth Not thread safe, in the context of C++, means "undefined behavior if two threads try to do it".  So yes, it has to be thread safe to check if initialization happened, but there are acceptable failure conditions.  For example, false positives are ok, so long as the false positive leads to a second reliable check; false negatives are not ok.  Such a system is still "thread safe", in that multiple threads behavior ends up in a set of defined possibilities, but not "thread safe" as in "behaves like non-threaded code" or what have you.

Comment: @Yak Post a  link to where in the standard it says "it has to be thread safe to check if initialization happened"

Comment: @NeilButterworth The behavior is defined.  It may not format your hard drive, for example; If you violate thread safety in the context of C++ you permit undefined behavior; nasal demons, hard drive formatting, reading wrong value, reading a partly wrong value, caching the value before it was read, reading values whose state is inconsistent, or *anything*.  Once the behavior is defined, it is "thead safe".